# Is there a URL query parameter for Google Messages for Web to specify a number to call?

Tags: google-messages, google-fi

My phone is on Google Fi, and I use Messages for Web on the desktop to send and receive calls and texts.  It generally works great.

I'm trying to get it to work with the tel: protocol, however, and running into issues.  I can set the protocol handler to open MfW, even directly to the "new call" page by using `https://messages.google.com/web/calls/new`.  But nothing obvious beyond that lets me specify to actually make a call to a number, or even pre-fill it in the new call box so I could just click the button.

Things I've tried:

- `https://messages.google.com/web/calls/new/<number>`
- `https://messages.google.com/web/calls/new?call=<number>`
- `https://messages.google.com/web/calls/new?dial=<number>`
- `https://messages.google.com/web/calls/new?to=<number>`
- `https://messages.google.com/web/calls/new?nc=<number>`
- `https://messages.google.com/web/calls/new?a=<number>`

Worst-case, I can write a user script which will lurk on the messages app and sniff query parameters and then manually inject it into the DOM, but if there's a simple URL I can just stick in the protocol handling settings, I'd prefer that.

[image: Screenshot of Google Fi Messages for Web]

Comment: How did you get to that URL in the 1st place? I don't see anything in the interface that would suggest doing phone calls. And the URL by default redirects me to SMSes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - the base url referenced above is the href for the "calls" button on the left side of the interface?